# Store Result of SVN Command in Variable

Tags: svn

I'm trying to get the username from the transaction in SVN committing to a repo.

I wrote the following in the `pre-commit hook`:

```
REPOS="$1"
TXN="$2"

touch /root/home/r/WC/log.log
AUTHOR="$(svnlook author -t $TXN $REPOS)"    
echo $AUTHOR >> /root/home/r/WC/log.log     

exit 0
```

And the result is `$(svnlook author -t 12-r /root/home/r/REPO)`

Apparently the TXN and REPOS variables were interpolated but the `svnlook author` command was not executed.

I have tried other ways of writing the command, such as

```
AUTHOR=$(svnlook author -t $TVN $REPOS)    # returned syntax error
AUTHOR=`svnlook author -t $TVN $REPOS`     # did not execute the svnlook command
```

I'm running SVN 1.8 on Solaris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In pre-commit, the `svnlook` command might not be defined which is why you're getting it as is in string format.

You need to find out the path for `svnlook` by executing `which svnlook` on your command line.

It will return something like `/nettools/subversion/svn1.8.10/bin/`

Now, you can do the following:

```
AUTHOR=`/nettools/subversion/svn1.8.10/bin/svnlook author -t $TXN $REPOS`
```

Then `echo "$AUTHOR"`